# Using html and css to create "swipe" screen

Tags: android, html, ios, css

On the mobile version of my web site, I have 32x32px sized product images. I have it shown as 4 columns and 4 or 5 rows. Is it possible to design it so that a user can swipe so a new set of product images appear? I have a total of 80 images.

I would like to replicate the experience of a smart phone where you swipe your screen to view more apps.

Comment: this question is a little bit unclear. could you please be more specific? it would help answerers and readers.

Comment: Is it possible to swipe right across the screen to see a new set of product images appear and swipe back left to see the original product images?

Comment: Gotcha . Thanks for clearing that up!